# How to call balance_of function using taquito i am facing a issue of parameters

Tags: taquito

I am calling balance_of function of contract  using taquito but i am facing issue that how to pass parameters address and token value in it as it sit showing error
const createInstance=async(res,obj,i)=>
{

```
const contract = await Tezos.wallet.at('KT1M81KrJr6TxYLkZkVqcpSTNKGoya8XytWT').then(async(instance) => {  
    let methods = instance.parameterSchema.ExtractSignatures();
    console.log("<====>",methods)

    let number =0
    const balance = await instance.methods.balance_of({"address":"tz1YTMzKPWur5nm1sXTaHeNgAJeJX4E6kgbh"},0).then(output => {  

    console.log("balance is",output)
    })  
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

console.log("Instance is");

}

Answer (score 0):

For now, Taquito doesn't work with entrypoints that require a value of type `contract`, so you cannot call the `balance_of` entrypoint of an FA2 contract from Taquito.
In general, you wouldn't need it because the entrypoint is reserved to get the balance of a user on-chain. With Taquito, you can read the balance directly from the `ledger` bigmap in the storage.